# Given a sorted array Arr of size N and a number X, you need to find the number of occurrences of X in Arr

Tags: java, arrays, function, sorting, search

```
class Solution {
int count(int[] arr, int n, int x) {
    int k = getFirst(arr, n, x);
    int l = getLast(arr, n, x);
    
    return l-k;
    
}

int getFirst(int arr[], int n, int x){
    int high = n-1;
    int low = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    while(low<=high){
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        
        if(arr[mid] == arr[x]){
            while(arr[mid] == arr[x]){
                mid--;
            }
            i = mid+1;
            return i;
        }else if(arr[mid] > arr[x]){
            high = mid-1;
        }else{
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
int getLast(int arr[], int n, int x){
    int high = n-1;
    int low = 0;
    int j = 1;
    
    while(low<=high){
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        
        if(arr[mid] == arr[x]){
            while(arr[mid] == arr[x]){
                mid++;
            }
            j += mid- 1;
            return j;
        }else if(arr[mid] > arr[x]){
            high = mid-1;
        }else{
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

}

question description :- i/p --> {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3} x = 2  ||  o/p --> 4.
i can't understand that what's wrong with my solution. like it always gives either the 4 in output or index out of bound. but where it is going to stuck. can anyone please take some time and try to figure out that what's the problem beacuse i am not able to understand that.

Comment: So, am I seeing this correctly that you are trying to get and subtract the indizes of the first and last occurrence of the searched value instead of ... you know ... simply counting the occurrences? Why?

Comment: As this is a **sorted array** you could take advantage of it and use  another more efficient way - eg. binary search?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `for` loop and increment a counter variable every time one of the elements within the array == x?

Answer (score 0):

why not simply check the equivalence between the number X and the element in the sorted array?

I need to make sure that you said this is a sorted array. If it is, we could simply use the binary search to find the nearest element in the list. and then count the occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question the array is sorted and you want to count the occurrences of a particular element if it is present. This is a digression about binary search with the little difference that you have to search for an element in one array and see if the adiacent elements on the left and on the right are equal to your element. You can use the [`Arrays#binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-) method like below:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static int binarySearchCount(int[] a, int key) {
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(a, key);
        
        if (index < 0) { return 0; }
        
        int count = 1;
        //look for the adiacent elements on the left
        for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0 && a[i] == key; --i) { ++count; }

        //look for the adiacent elements on the right
        for (int i = index + 1; i < a.length && a[i] == key; ++i) { ++count; }


        return count;
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3};
        System.out.println(binarySearchCount(a, 2)); //<-- it will print 4
        System.out.println(binarySearchCount(a, 0)); //<-- it will print 0
    }
}
```

If you have to code your binary search version, you have to just substitute your code to the`Arrays#binarySearch` method in the `binarySearchCount` function.